# Replace data from firebase database to sitemap.xml

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, firebase

Here is my coding, we connect with firebase database

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
app.listen(3000)
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile)  
app.use(express.static('public'))
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var sm = require('sitemap')

var firebase = require('firebase').initializeApp({
    apiKey: "xx",
    authDomain: "xx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://xx.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "xx",
    storageBucket: "xx.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "xx"
  });
```

I query data from firebase database

```
    database = firebase.database();
    var ref = database.ref('urls');
    ref.on('value', gotData, errData);

    function gotData(data){
        console.log(data.val())    
    }
```

I get result as below

```
{ salmon: 
   { count: 1,
     last_res: 10,
     url_site: 'salmon' },
  'salmon-food': 
   { count: 1,
     last_res: 601,
     url_site: 'salmon-food' } }
```

I need to add url_site into 'pagex' only last_res < 5

```
var sitemap = sm.createSitemap({ 
    hostname: 'xxx.com',
    cacheTime: 600000,        // 600 sec - cache purge period 
    urls: [
        { url: '/pagex/'},
        { url: '/pagex/'},
        { url: '/pagex/'},
        { url: '/pagex/'}
    ]
});
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this assuming your firebase result is stored in the variable `result` -

```
const urls = Object.keys(result)
                 .filter(key => result[key].last_res < 5)
                 .map(key => ({url: '/' + result[key].url_site + '/'}))
```

This will give you an array like -

```
[ { url: '/salmon/' }, { url: '/salmon-food/' } ]
```

Then you can use it -

```
var sitemap = sm.createSitemap({ 
    hostname: 'xxx.com',
    cacheTime: 600000,        // 600 sec - cache purge period 
    urls: urls
});
```

Comment: I got `urls = [ { url: '/salmon/' }, { url: '/salmon-food/' } ]` already 
but It's error on `urls: urls > ReferenceError: urls is not defined`

Comment: Its seem cant return value 'urls' outside the function

Comment: I mean can you post code about how you are using my code and at what line the error is occuring? It's hard to tell the error otherwise.

Comment: on `urls: urls > ReferenceError: urls is not defined` Its seem cant return urls in function. I try run `console.log(urls)` in function, its work fine. but I cant run `console.log(urls)` outside the function